# Oracle - Excel view

Tags: sql, oracle, excel

Im using Oracle XE11g and Excel 2007. I've created a View in SQL Developer which selects fields from multiple tables. The intention is to allow Excel to import this View using ODBC. The problem is that the view isn't giving the data the way I want it in Excel

If I use my created view into Excel I get something like this:

```
personname - testname    - time     - objectname   - result - date
Edward     - RunningTest - 15:22:01 - Speed (km/h) - 12     - 24-04-2012
Edward     - RunningTest - 15:22:01 - Heart Rate   - 98     - 24-04-2012
Edward     - RunningTest - 15:22:01 - Power        - 50     - 24-04-2012
Edward     - RunningTest - 15:22:02 - Speed (km/h) - 13     - 24-04-2012
Edward     - RunningTest - 15:22:02 - Heart Rate   - 99     - 24-04-2012
Edward     - RunningTest - 15:22:02 - Power        - 12     - 24-04-2012
Edward     - RunningTest - 15:22:03 - Speed (km/h) - 12     - 24-04-2012
Edward     - RunningTest - 15:22:03 - Heart Rate   - 100    - 24-04-2012
Edward     - RunningTest - 15:22:03 - Power        - 12     - 24-04-2012
```

And this is the query of the view I use:

```
select psn.naam personname
, tst.name testname
, tms.seconds time
, obj.name objectname
, trt.result result
, dtm.days date
from persons psn
, results rst
, times tms
, tests tst
, objects obj
, dates dts
where psn.id=trt.persons_id
and obj.id=trt.objects_id
and obj.tests_id=tst.id
and trt.date_id=dts.id
and rst.times_id=tms.id
and tst.name='RunningTest'
```

Please note that the query is translated into English fieldnames so there might be some errors in it.

The way I'd like to have the data represented in Excel is like this:

```
Personname
Edward

Date
24-04-2012

    Time     - Speed (km/h) - Heart Rate - Power
    15:22:01 - 12           - 98         - 50
    15:22:02 - 13           - 99         - 52
    15:22:03 - 12           - 100        - 51
    etc------------
```

Is there any way to build the view so it shows the data like above?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A clarification: what's wrong, the data returned by the view or the data imported by Excel?

Comment: IMHO, such formatting should be made in the excel

Comment: The data returned by the view is wrong. The problem I have with formatting in Excel is that it should be dynamic. I just want the right data imported into Excel straight away. With those data I can then make graphs and some statisics on another tab page.

Comment: You need to rewrite your view as a pivot query, and given that you've got Oracle 11 you can make use of the the PIVOT addition to the SELECT statement.  Without having all the tables and data available to mess with, however, I can't offer much more than a direction to go.  Good luck.

Comment: Like @A.B.Cade says, the formatting will need to be done in Excel. A view will always return a table-like structure (generally as a recordset). It is then up to the presentation Tier (Excel in this case) to parse / display it how you want. Even if you were to use analytical partitions in your View, the output would still be in a table-like structure.

Comment: @Edwardo what do you mean by dynamic ,Do you expect the first Column would be first line in excel and then last column would be next line of data and then next line followed by other data in tabular form???

Comment: @psaaj12: Well, what i mean with dynamic is more that a test can contain a random number of timestamps. I mean a RunningTest could take 2 minutes or it could take 4 minutes. I need every timestamp with it's corresponding values (Speed, Heartrate etc) in those records.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.  The first is that your query isn't providing the data that you need in Excel.  This is a classic problem arising from using key-value pairs instead of a proper schema.

Here is one possible solution:

```
select psn.naam personname 
      , tst.name testname 
      , tms.seconds time 
      , rst1.result speed
      , rst2.result heartrate
      , rst3.result power
      , dtm.days date 
from persons psn 
     , results trt1 
     , results trt2 
     , results trt3 
     , times tms 
     , tests tst
     , objects obj 
     , dates dts 
where psn.id=trt.persons_id 
and obj.tests_id=tst.id 
and trt1.date_id=dts.id 
and trt2.date_id=dts.id 
and trt3.date_id=dts.id 
and trt1.times_id=tms.id 
and trt2.times_id=tms.id 
and trt3.times_id=tms.id 
and  ( ( obj.name = 'Speed (km/h)' and obj.id=trt1.objects_id )
       or  ( obj.name = 'Heart Rate' and obj.id=trt2.objects_id )
       or   ( obj.name = 'Power' and obj.id=trt3.objects_id )
      )
 and tst.name='RunningTest'
```

Caveat: your aliasing was mangled in translation so this may well not work, but the basic principle is you need three instances of the RESULTS table, one for each disctinct attribute you're recalling from the OBJECTNAMES table.

The second problem is that your layout doesn't match the result set.  This is another classic problem, this time associated with using the wrong tool for the job.  A spreadsheet is not really a GUI presentation tool.  The great strengths of Excel is working with matrices of columns and rows.  So normally it's a good fit for working with databases, because queries return columns and rows.

You're in a pickle because you want to display different some columns once and some coumns multiple times.  There are a number of different ways of working with this.

1. Use [an inline cursor expression](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:7866466844558) to return a jagged resultset.  Although frankly I don't know whether ODBC supports this and whether Excel will be able to render it.
2. Use two queries, one to return the "master data" - PersonName, Date - and one to retrieve the details - everything else.
3. Use your existing query to retrieve the full result set into one worksheet but present the user with a differnet worksheet which uses references to achieve the layout you require.
4. Use a proper GUI development tool to build your client application.  There are any number of them on the market.  Apex might be a good choice: [find out more](http://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html).

Comment: I just spent 20 minutes writing almost the exact same sql, though not as complete an answer. Must work faster! :)

Answer (score 1):

The following PIVOT query should get close to what you want, but without the data to play with I'm not 100% sure - but it should provide a starting point for you to work from:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT psn.NAAM PERSONNAME,
            tst.NAME TESTNAME,
            tms.SECONDS TIME,
            obj.NAME OBJECTNAME,
            rst.RESULT RESULT,
            dts.DAYS DATE
       FROM PERSONS psn,
            RESULTS rst,
            TIMES tms,
            TESTS tst,
            OBJECTS obj,
            DATES dts
       WHERE psn.ID = rst.PERSONS_ID AND
             obj.ID = rst.OBJECTS_ID AND
             obj.TESTS_ID = tst.ID AND
             trt.DATE_ID = dts.ID AND
             rst.TIMES_ID = tms.ID AND
             tst.NAME = 'RunningTest') t
   PIVOT(SUM(RESULT)
         FOR OBJECTNAME IN ('Speed (km/h)', 'Heart Rate', 'Power')));
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can kindly test and use existing answers and use below to insert end of line

```
Select name || chr(10) || chr(13) || date || chr(10) || chr(13)|| other select columns in your view
```

to achieve the desired results in Windows OS

Adopting Bob's answer with your desired results

```
SELECT PERSONNAME || chr(10) || chr(13) as PERSONNAME,
       DATE || chr(10) || chr(13) as DATE,
       chr(10) || chr(13) ||TESTNAME,
       OBJECTNAME,
       RESULT
  FROM (SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT psn.NAAM    PERSONNAME,
               tst.NAME    TESTNAME,
               tms.SECONDS TIME,
               obj.NAME    OBJECTNAME,
               rst.RESULT  RESULT,
               dts.DAYS    DATE
          FROM PERSONS psn,
               RESULTS rst,
               TIMES   tms,
               TESTS   tst,
               OBJECTS obj,
               DATES   dts
         WHERE psn.ID = rst.PERSONS_ID
           AND obj.ID = rst.OBJECTS_ID
           AND obj.TESTS_ID = tst.ID
           AND trt.DATE_ID = dts.ID
           AND rst.TIMES_ID = tms.ID
           AND tst.NAME = 'RunningTest') t PIVOT(SUM(RESULT) 
           FOR OBJECTNAME IN ('Speed (km/h)', 'Heart Rate', 'Power')));
```